# Azure DevOps - Automatically run rails migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, azure, docker, deployment, rails-migrations

I created a Azure devops project that deploys my code from Github. My project is a Rails app that runs on Docker. When I create the Azure DevOps project, it creates the CI/CD pipelines for me. The deployment works, but I can't figure out how to automatically migrate the database when we deploy. I know I can do it manually, but I prefer not to as we might forget when we deploy.

I tried to run the following commands in the "Post Deployment Actions"

- `rake db:migrate`
- `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
- `rbenv exec bundle exec rake db:migrate`
- `docker-compose run web rake db:migrate`

I've also generated my own kuduscript (using kuduscript) to add in the line for migration but it did not work. I don't know if it's because it's not reading my deployment script or if that line doesn't work.

Am I missing something? Should I try to figure out how to migrate through Docker instead? I've looked at all these links but they all run the migration manually.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-ruby
https://medium.com/paris-rb/deploying-your-rails-postgresql-app-on-microsoft-azure-180f8a9fab47
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/tutorial-ruby-postgres-app

Answer (score 1):

So not sure if you ever figured this out but I just had to do this for a migration I'm working on. The best way to do what you're after from what I've found is to setup a stage in your release pipeline like so:

[stage setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFiRc.png)

Where basically:

- Your service connection logs into the container registry
- Pulls the image you just built and pushed to the registry
- Use a docker run command to then run your image with all the necessary environment variables and anything else needed to run it properly.
- You can then use another task if needed to run a docker exec bundle exec rake db:migrate

If the migrate task runs successfully it should exit 0 allowing you to then run your app service on the latest tagged image with the correct database changes already done.

Comment: Will this work if the database service is configured to be accessed through a Private Endpoint?